# How to increase the space between the two events in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to increase the space between two events in month view of full calendar.

Answer (score 6):

you need to modify css element of event in [EventRender Function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

you can achieve spacing between events like this

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {

            $(element).css("margin-top", "5px");


              $(element).css("margin-bottom", "5px");

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have to ensure one thing that, instead of this we can adjust the top value of the event. If u know tell how.

Comment: hmmm.. im updating my answer

Comment: you want something like  $(element).css("margin-top", "5px"); right??...Do you find this solution useful ?

Comment: @AnilMahajan Do you know of any way to increase the gap of the rightmost events so that the slot in the back is easily clickable?

Comment: A bit late to the party, but add some CSS:
`.fc-event-container .fc-event {
    margin-right: 10px;
}`