# How to make the bottom part of a box move on 'append' of a new element in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an element that appends on hover. What I'd like to happen is that it makes the bottom part of the box that it's in move down to accommodate it, but that does not happen.

Here is an example:

Before hover:

[image]

After hover:

[image]

Comment: What is the code that you are currently using? Please reproduce your issue through a demo.

Comment: pleasae provide code or jsfiddle with images too. we can't help by only images.

Comment: @Tapha provide your code

Comment: the problem required specific (as I suspected) modification of the JQuery plugin I was using, and therefore could not really be reproduced (as I suspected). I have provided a link to the correct answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The problems is solved by specifying a margin in the 'EventRender' action of the FullCalendar plugin.

As so: [How to increase the space between the two events in fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192750/how-to-increase-the-space-between-the-two-events-in-fullcalendar/22193324#22193324)

Answer (score 0):

You need two events on your table cell

i.e `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("div").on("mouseenter",function(){
               $("span").show();    
            }).on("mouseleave",function(){
               $("span").hide();    
            });
        });
```

See an example here, modify as per your need

> **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/qs2Lqbeu/1/)**

Comment: I guess the OP wanted to add some padding to the box. Currently in the screenshot there is no enough space at the bottom of the appended element.

Comment: height must be auto of the cell in which element must be added, and other than that, if you are adding element dynamically, height or padding will work